# Django: handle CSRF error as form error

Tags: django

When a Django form has a CSRF error, it redirects to a 403 page. Is there any way to handle that as a form error (i.e. showing an error message in the form page) instead of redirecting?

UPDATE: I know I can customize the 403 page. That's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Only showing an error message in case of a CSRF attack is really not what you want to do in my opinion. A redirection seems way more appropriate. Now has the Django documentation says,

> By default, a ‘403 Forbidden’ response is sent to the user if an
>   incoming request fails the checks performed by CsrfViewMiddleware.
>   This should usually only be seen when there is a genuine Cross Site
>   Request Forgery, or when, due to a programming error, the CSRF token
>   has not been included with a POST form.
>
> The error page, however, is not very friendly, so you may want to
>   provide your own view for handling this condition. To do this, simply
>   set the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.

Therefore, you should look at the [`CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW) setting.

Comment: Yes, I know I can create my own view. But my client insists that all errors should be shown as form errors.